# Looping through a list of different objects that share the same super class and get one specific type

Tags: java, refactoring, observable, observer-pattern, observers

I'm practicing the Observer Design Pattern using Java. 
I have 2 types of Customers. 
One is interested into the price while the other one by the availability.
 I'm trying to refactor this following code :

```
public void setAvailable(boolean available) {

    this.available = available;
    if (this.available == true)
        for (Iobserver o : allObservers) {
            if (o instanceof CustomerAvailabilityObserver)
                notify(o);
        }
}
```

Someone told me that whenever you I use `instanceof` there is a bad smell in my code that could be fixed.
 Any Idea in how to rewrite the for loop? Btw the observers are stored in an `ArrayList`.

Comment: You could store two lists in the first place

Comment: @user7: Two lists do not represent a clean approach, because they are more complex to maintain/synchronize.

Comment: @user7 yes It could be a good solution. but Antot's now making me think about the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You could write in the Customer classes functions that determine their interests:

```
boolean notifyOnAvailabilityChange();
boolean notifyOnPriceChange();
```

so you could write the loop as something like

```
allObservers.filter(o -> o.notifyOnAvailabilityChange()).forEach(this::notify);
```

Comment: I guess I can get rid of different type of customers and implement all the different notification factors In the class Customer?

Comment: I can't say. I don't know why you had different implementations in the first place.

Comment: I sent my new implementation as an answer give it a look  if you can :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension of Turo@'s answer.

The basic idea is that each of the Observers will tell what events (state change) they are interested in. Then, when an event occurs (some state like price or availability changes) you notify *only* those that are interested in that event.

I call each of the notifiable state changes (like price, availability) as a `Factor`. The Observers will tell the list of factors they are interested in.

```
enum Factors {
   PRICE,
   AVAILABILITY
   //and so on
}
```

Observer interface will have a method to let the Observer return the list of interested Factors

```
interface IObserver {
    List<Factors> interestedFactors();
    //other existing methods
}
```

Example observer:

```
class Observer1 implements IObserver {
    @Override
    public List<Factors> interestedFactors() {
        return ImmutableList.of(Factors.PRICE);
    }
}
class Observer2 implements IObserver {
    @Override
    public List<Factors> interestedFactors() {
        //Some might be interested in multiple states
        return ImmutableList.of(Factors.PRICE, Factors.AVAILABILITY);
    }
}
```

Once a state changes, you can filter the observers that are interested in that state and can notify them.

```
allObservers.stream()
            .filter(observer -> observer.interestedFactors().contains(Factors.<whatever_the_cuurent_state_change_is>))
            .forEach(observer -> notify(observer));
```

**Pros:**

1. The `Subject` is not coupled to any other the Observers.
2. Easier to add new types of state (other than price, availability)

**Cons:**

1. If a new state is introduced and if all the existing Observers must be notified of it, then it has to be added to all the existing Observer's `interestedFactors` list.

Comment: ImmutableList.of doesn't work for me. I tried to use Collections.unmodifiableList(list); but I get this error : Error Message: The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments ...

Comment: @MousKamel It was from Google Guava. I have shown it just to demonstrate returning a list of Factors. You can use whatever is convenient for you. Simple ArrayList will do.

Comment: I didnt something different it looks nice now and it work but I have to fix an OpenClose Probleme

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to Turo and User7. This is what I did. I dunno if its the best solution because not only I have to subsribe to the observers but the custumers have to kind of select their interests too. it is not straight forward like subscribing to the price or availability.

```
public enum Factors {
    AVAILABILITY, PRICE
}
```

then in my Customer Class thats where we set the interests in the observation hashmap.

```
public class Customer implements Iobserver {
    String name;
    String email;

    private EnumMap<Factors, Boolean> observations = new EnumMap<Factors, Boolean>(Factors.class);

    public Customer(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;

        for (Factors factor : Factors.values()) {
            observations.put(factor, false);
        }
    }

    public void setObsevation(Factors factor, Boolean isInterested) {
        observations.put(factor, isInterested);
    }

    public boolean getObservation(Factors factor) {
        return observations.get(factor);
    }

    public void update(Product p, Factors factor) {

        System.out.println("Dear customer " + this.name + ", the " + factor.toString().toLowerCase() + " of "+ p.getProduct() + " has changed! ");

    }
}
```

and in my Product class, where the list of observers resides.I added this.

```
public void setPrix(float prix) {
        if (prix != this.prix) {
            this.prix = prix;

            for (Iobserver o : allObservers) {
                if (o.getObservation(Factors.PRICE)) {
                    notify(o,Factors.PRICE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setAvailable(boolean available) {

        this.available = available;
        if (this.available == true)
            for (Iobserver o : allObservers) {
                if (o.getObservation(Factors.AVAILABILITY))
                    notify(o,Factors.AVAILABILITY);
            }
    }

    public void notify(Iobserver o, Factors factor) {
        o.update(this,factor);
    }
```

I can just add a strategy after for each factor notification.

Comment: Working with this factors i wouldn't work with this ObservationsMap but call o.update(this, factor) every time and let the customer decide wether to return instantly. And by the way, i would write `if (this.available)`